# Annotate ggplot with an extra tick and label

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can you help me annotate a ggplot2 scatterplot?

To a typical scatter plot (black):

```
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:100), y=sort(rexp(100, 2), decreasing = T))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
```

I want to add annotations in the form of an extra tick and a custom label (red):

Example image:

[image]

Comment: see  `scale_x_continuous`

Comment: So I can use `scale_x_continuous` to change the format & place of all ticks, but can I use it to add a single custom tick+label? I don't see that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Four solutions.

The first uses `scale_x_continuous` to add the additional element then uses `theme` to customize the new text and tick mark (plus some additional tweaking).

The second uses `annotate_custom` to create new grobs: a text grob,  and a line grob. The locations of the grobs are in data coordinates. A consequence is that the positioning of the grob will change if the limits of y-axis changes. Hence, the y-axis is fixed in the example below. Also, `annotation_custom` is attempting to plot outside the plot panel. By default, clipping of the plot panel is turned on. It needs to be turned off.

The third is a variation on the second (and draws on code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722610/custom-annotation-with-npc-coordinates-in-ggplot2)). The default coordinate system for grobs is 'npc', so position the grobs vertically during the construction of the grobs. The positioning of the grobs using `annotation_custom` uses data coordinates, so position the grobs horizontally in `annotation_custom`. Thus, unlike the second solution, the positioning of the grobs in this solution is independent of the range of the y values.

The fourth uses `viewports`. It sets up a more convenient unit system for locating the text and tick mark. In the x direction, the location uses data coordinates; in the y direction, the location uses "npc" coordinates. Thus, in this solution too, the positioning of the grobs is independent of the range of the y values.

**First Solution**

```
## scale_x_continuous then adjust colour for additional element 
## in the x-axis text and ticks
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:100), y=sort(rexp(100, 2), decreasing = T))

p = ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,25,30,50,75,100), labels = c("0","25","xyz","50","75","100")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = c("black", "black", "red", "black", "black", "black")),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = c("black", "black", "red", "black", "black", "black"),
                          size = c(.5,.5,1,.5,.5,.5)))

# y-axis to match x-axis
p = p + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black"))

# Remove the extra grid line
p = p + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = c("white", "white", NA, "white", "white", "white")))
p
```

[image]

**Second Solution**

```
## annotation_custom then turn off clipping
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:100), y=sort(rexp(100, 2), decreasing = T))

p = ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 4)) +
 annotation_custom(textGrob("xyz", gp = gpar(col = "red")), 
        xmin=30, xmax=30,ymin=-.4, ymax=-.4) +
 annotation_custom(segmentsGrob(gp = gpar(col = "red", lwd = 2)), 
        xmin=30, xmax=30,ymin=-.25, ymax=-.15)

g = ggplotGrob(p)
g$layout$clip[g$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

**Third Solution**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:100), y=sort(rexp(100, 2), decreasing = T))

p = ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() 

gtext = textGrob("xyz", y = -.05, gp = gpar(col = "red"))
gline = linesGrob(y = c(-.02, .02),  gp = gpar(col = "red", lwd = 2)) 

p = p + annotation_custom(gtext, xmin=30, xmax=30, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
        annotation_custom(gline, xmin=30, xmax=30, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)

g = ggplotGrob(p)
g$layout$clip[g$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

**Fourth Solution**

***Updated to ggplot2 v3.0.0***

```
## Viewports
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:100), y=sort(rexp(100, 2), decreasing = T))

(p = ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point())


# Search for the plot panel using regular expressions
Tree = as.character(current.vpTree())
pos = gregexpr("\\[panel.*?\\]", Tree)
match = unlist(regmatches(Tree, pos))
match = gsub("^\\[(panel.*?)\\]$", "\\1", match) # remove square brackets
downViewport(match)

#######
# Or find the plot panel yourself
#  current.vpTree() # Find the plot panel
#  downViewport("panel.6-4-6-4")
#####

# Get the limits of the ggplot's x-scale, including the expansion.
x.axis.limits = ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params[[1]][["x.range"]]

# Set up units in the plot panel so that the x-axis units are, in effect, "native",
# but y-axis units are, in effect, "npc".
pushViewport(dataViewport(yscale = c(0, 1), xscale = x.axis.limits, clip = "off"))
grid.text("xyz", x = 30, y = -.05, just = "center", gp = gpar(col = "red"), default.units = "native")
grid.lines(x = 30, y = c(.02, -.02), gp = gpar(col = "red", lwd = 2), default.units = "native") 

upViewport(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, nothing to add.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will pick door number 2 ;)

Comment: They sure make it difficult to do something so useful.

Answer (score 2):

**Fifth solution:** Simply annotate with a text layer. A tick can be hacked with "|" or capital "i" (I) (only works using sans serif font)

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1:100), y = sort(rexp(100, 2), decreasing = T))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(
    x = 30, y = -Inf, label = "I\nxyz", geom = "text",
    color = "red",
    lineheight = .6,
    vjust = .8
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The following will get you the xyz label and a line above it, you might need to play about with the x and y position for both to get it exactly where you want it.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + annotate(x=27, y=0, label="xyz", color="red") +annotate(x=27, ymin=-1, ymax=1, color="red")
```

More info [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/annotate.html) if needed.

Comment: `annotate` only allows to add annotations inside plots. That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Wrong. annotate let's you very well add annotations outside the plot.