# annotate edge of plot without changing plot limits or setting "expand" to 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot object. I want to use `annotate()` to add a label to the top of the plot, so that the upper edge of the label is also the upper edge of the plot. When using default settings, this doesn't seem possible: adding an annotation at the upper edge of the plot causes the upper y-limit to increase.

One can get around this problem by specifying `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))` when creating the plot. But I don't want to do that, partly because I like the y limits created by the default `expand` setting. Given this constraint, is it possible to use `annotate()` to position a label at the top of the plot?

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
p    <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
yMax <- layer_scales(p)$y$range$range[2]  # upper y-limit
p + annotate("label", x = 30, y = yMax, vjust = "top", label = "X")
```

And here is the result:

[image]

You see that the annotation is not at the top of the plot. Instead, consistent with the default "expand" settings, the y-limit of the plot has changed.

Possible solutions:

1. Figure out the y-limits implied by the default `expand` setting. Then use `scale_y_continuous()` to both set the y limits and set `expand = c(0, 0)`. This solution will give me the y limits that I want, and it will place the label appropriately. I know how to implement it, but it seems a bit cumbersome. It would also prevent other annotations at the top of the figure from changing the y-limit of the plot -- and I don't want the solution to affect annotations other than the one that I describe here.
2. Use `annotation_custom()`, which doesn't change plot limits in the same way. @baptiste suggests a solution like that in [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31736633/697473). But `annotation_custom()` requires a grob. In practice, the annotations that I use may be more complicated than the label in this example, and I won't always know how to create them as a grob that can be passed to `annotation_custom()`. In addition, I've had some trouble positioning grobs with `annotation_custom()` while also specifying their exact sizes.

That said, I am quite open to `annotation_custom()`-based solutions. And perhaps there are solutions other than the two that I've sketched above.

I've read many SO posts on changing plot limits, but I haven't found any that speak to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution for that is setting `y = Inf` instead of using the maximum value found of the y-axis (`yMax`). The code would be like that then:

```
# load library
library(ggplot2)
# load data
data(mtcars)
# define plot
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p + annotate("label", x = 30, y = Inf, vjust = "top", label = "X")
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that `Inf` could be used to prevent the plot-expanding behavior that I described in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(label = "X", x = 30, y = max(mtcars$wt))
```

Comment: Thank you -- but it's not quite right. If you run the code, you'll see that positioning the label in this way increases the upper y-limit of the plot. As a result, the label isn't positioned at the top of the plot.