# Plotting data with R. How to break coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a `geom_point()` layer using ggplot. In my plot, I have one dot located very far away from the rest along the y axis. As a result, the data visualization loses granularity and displays a bunch of little dots close together, as well as a single isolated dot high and far away from the rest.

I do not want to exclude the outlier. Instead, I would like to break the y-axis coordinates, for instance displaying `ylim = c(0, 220)` followed by `c(2000, 2100)`. However, I did not succeed using `coord_cartesian` or `scale_y_continuous`.

Anyone knows how can I make this works, or possibly suggest any alternative solutions? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do so in ggplot by design. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis) for further discussion & some possible alternatives.

Comment: Something from [ggplot2-custom-grob-over-axis-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733972/ggplot2-custom-grob-over-axis-lines/40622343#40622343) might help. But it will not be easy.

Comment: Perhaps use `ggforce::facet_zoom` instead.

Comment: Thank you all. You took time to read and to answer to the question I had. I will solve this question. Be well