# How to create a break in the y-axis (a broken axis) in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create a break in the y-axis, so I can show very low values, skip 90% of the y-axis and then show the very high values. How would I do this in r with ggplot?

Code is not needed, this is more of a conceptual question. I want something like below.

[image]

Comment: You can't by design, as cut axes produce misleading graphs. `scale_y_log10` or facetting may be good alternatives.

Comment: Maybe you can take something from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733972/ggplot2-custom-grob-over-axis-lines/40622343#40622343)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions scale_x_discrete() and scale_y_discrete() are used to customize discrete x and y axis, respectively. Just define your own breaks.

```
scale_x_discrete(name, breaks, labels, limits)
scale_y_discrete(name, breaks, labels, limits)
```

> 1. name : x or y axis labels
> 2. breaks : control the breaks in the guide
>      (axis ticks, grid lines, …). Among the possible values, there are :
>          NULL : hide all breaks    waiver() : the default break computation    a character or numeric vector specifying which breaks
>      to display
> 3. labels : labels of axis tick marks. Allowed values are :      NULL for no labels      waiver() for the default labels     character
>      vector to be used for break labels
> 4. limits : a character vector indicating the data
>      range

Reference this [link](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels)

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear