# Difference in plot when shown in R Studio and exported with ggsave()

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I want to add an additional tick to my plot in ggplot2, and used Solution 2 as described in the post [Annotate ggplot with an extra tick and label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824773/annotate-ggplot-with-an-extra-tick-and-label).

It worked fine for me, giving the following result in R Studio:

[image]

But when I try to save the result using `ggsave()` to create the a .pdf, .ps, or .png file, the red number is cut off half like this:

[image]

I have the feeling that the inner plot is printed first and later the margins are plotted on top of this.

Anybody has a hint?

Comment: Did you try changing the `scale` and dimensions in ggsave? If not oculd you try?

Comment: If you didn't specify the plot argument in `ggsave()`, try doing it explicitly. i.e.  `ggsave(file name = "some.file.name", plot = grid.draw(g), ...)`

Comment: Can you post your code for the plot?

Comment: Thank you Z. Lin! I just had a  `grid.draw(g)` instead of `g <- grid.draw(g)`. This dot in R always activates my python brain region :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Z. Lin! I just had a  `grid.draw(g)` instead of `g <- grid.draw(g)`. This dot in R always activates my python brain region :)