# Adding numeric label to geom_hline in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2

I have produced the graph pictured using the following code -

```
ggboxplot(xray50g, x = "SupplyingSite", y = "PercentPopAff", 
          fill = "SupplyingSite", legend = "none") +
  geom_point() +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
  # ADD HORIZONTAL LINE AT BASE MEAN
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(xray50g$PercentPopAff), linetype = 2)
```

What I would like to do is label the horizontal geom_hline with it's numeric value so that it appears on the y axis.

I have provided an example of what I would like to achieve in the second image.
Could somebody please help with the code to achieve this for my plot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a really great answer that should help you out [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824773/annotate-ggplot-with-an-extra-tick-and-label).  As long as you are okay with formatting the "extra tick" to match the existing axis, the easiest solution is to just create your axis breaks manually and specify within `scale_y_continuous`.  See below where I use an example to label a vertical dotted line on the x-axis using this method.

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000, mean = 0.5))

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5, linetype=2) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(from=-4,to=4,by=2), 0.5))
```

[image]

Again, for other methods, including those where you want the extra tick mark formatted differently than the rest of the axis, check [the top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824773/annotate-ggplot-with-an-extra-tick-and-label).